# Repeating a body-pronoun in a sentence is obligation, option, or prohibited?

Tags: pronouns, subject-pronouns

> "Yesterday **we** went to a supermarket and (**we**?) bought beef and chicken"?

The second body-pronoun in the same sentence is obligation, option (=up to you), or prohibited if we are talking about standard English?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Second or subsequent pronouns are optional in standard English, and are often omitted for the sake of brevity and elegance. We went to the airport and boarded a plane. We went to the zoo and saw a lion. I woke up, got out of bed, dressed, combed my hair, and went to the kitchen.